# PC Game combining "Match 3" and "Tower Defense"

Tags: story-identification, video-games

I think I played this within the last five years. The basic concept was of someone trying to defend their kingdom against oncoming hordes. The method for providing that defense involved doing a "match 3" kind of game to summon various spells. I remember there was a spell for creating a rock, and one for creating a golem. The rock provided a static defense against the creatures coming upon a row, and I think the golem cleared out a row. The assaults happened in stages, I think involving a backstory of conflicts of mage kings. At least one level involved an assault of the undead, and I think Ogres and Genies played into it. Completing a match had an effect in and of itself, but additional spells were available via scrolls for past victories.

I think I acquired this via IndieRoyale/Desura before that collapsed, which suggests it might exist as a Steam game.

Comment: IndieGala is still around.  Still get spam from them at least...

Comment: ReignMaker is the closest match I can find, even that doesn't look like it, and it was too easily found.  Too many made in a garage games doing something similar.

Comment: @Radhill: I misspoke. I forget the name of the service, but they were tied to Desura at the time. And yes, Reignmaker looks like the right answer. I snapped off the question on my way to bed after very little research. Post that as an answer and I'll upvote it.

Comment: IndieRoyale was the service I was associating this with, but it looks like I did download it for Steam as well.

Comment: @radhil I've posted an answer, but if you'd like to post one, even using my content, I'd be content to accept it.

Comment: RL distractions. Take it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Radhill found the game in question, [*Reignmaker*](https://store.steampowered.com/app/286200/ReignMaker/).

> ReignMaker: Saving the World One Tower at a Time. ReignMaker is a match-3 game with tower defense, city building, and political strategy elements. Your policy decisions determine the fate of your city and the direction of the story. Your match-3 and tower defense skills determine the fate of the world.